# wordpress function - do not recognise syntax/method

Tags: php, wordpress

I do not recognise the way this function is written and so I can't tell what is going on.

```
twentyfourteen\mobile\get_comments::format_comment( $comment, $args, $depth );
```

What is going on with this part ?

```
twentyfourteen\mobile\get_comments::
```

It looks like a file path but of course it does not exist - no amount of googling is giving me any clues.

apologies in advance for being such a numpty.

Comment: I believe it's using a function found in WP `content/twentyfourteen/mobile/getcomments.php` `format_comment()`

Comment: that's a fully qualified class name. The class is `get_comments` in the `twentyfourteen\mobile` namespace. `format_comment` is a static method inside that class

Comment: ok that's a clue, 

so what is the twentyfourteen\mobile namespace? and how is a namespace created/defined?

Comment: @pokebit 
/twentyfourteen/mobile/*.*   does not exist, no such path

Comment: @Alex Tartan Thank you, that's the clue I needed, found what I needed to complete the picture in /plugins/twentyfourteen/classes/